# Date comparion/consecutive date grouping

Tags: python, date, compare, iteration

Im trying to write a function which identifies groups of dates, and measures the size of the group.

The function will take a list of elements (the elements are individual lines from a CSV file with dates in) which have been sorted in date order. The list may be 0 to n elements long. I wish to write the list as it was inputted, with the addition of the size of the date-group.

for example, the list

```
Bill 01/01/2011

Bill 02/01/2011

Bill 03/01/2011

Bill 05/01/2011

Bill 07/01/2011
```

should be output (ideally printed to a file) as

```
Bill 01/01/2011 3

Bill 02/01/2011  3

Bill 03/01/2011  3

Bill 05/01/2011  1

Bill 07/01/2011  1.
```

I have a function already called `isBeside(string1, string2)` which returns the delta between the two.

My attempt so far is this (an iterative mess, im sure python can be more elegant than this)

Note `coll[i][1]` contains the date element of the CSV line.

```
def printSet(coll):
    setSize = len(coll)
    if setSize == 0:
    #dont need to do anything
elif setSize == 1:

    for i in coll:
        print i, 1

elif setSize > 1:

    printBuffer = [] ##new buffer list which will hold sequential dates, 
                        until a non-sequential one is found
    printBuffer.append(coll[0]) #add the first item
    print 'Adding ' + str(coll[0])

    for i in range(0, len(coll)-1):

        print 'Comparing ', coll[i][1], coll[i+1][1], isBeside(coll[i][1],  coll[i+1][1])

        if isBeside(coll[i][1],  coll[i+1][1]) == 1:
            printBuffer.append(coll[i+1])
            print 'Adding ' + str(coll[i+1])
        else:
            for j in printBuffer:
                print j, len(printBuffer)
            printBuffer = []
            printBuffer.append(coll[i])

return
```

Comment: This is something a database is VERY good at. Have you considered using a database instead?

Comment: Yeah. My problem with that is I have lots of people and other variables in the CSV file. Procedurally seemed to be the way forward for me. Ill need to check over weekends/working days eventually too, so I dont think a DB would hold up, although will to be proven otherwise. I feel like im come CLOSE with this method and don't want to throw it away :)

Comment: Are the dates in month/day/year format, or day/month/year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

coll = [['Bill', date(2011,1,1)],
        ['Bill', date(2011,1,2)],
        ['Bill', date(2011,1,3)],
        ['Bill', date(2011,1,5)],
        ['Bill', date(2011,1,7)]]

res = []
group = [coll[0]]
i = 1

while i < len(coll):
    row = coll[i]
    last_in_group = group[-1]

    # use your isBeside() function here...
    if row[1] - last_in_group[1] == timedelta(days=1):
        # consecutive, append to current group..
        group.append(row)
    else:
        # not consecutive, start new group.
        res.append(group)
        group = [row]
    i += 1

res.append(group)

for group in res:
    for row in group:
        for item in row:
            print item,
        print len(group)
```

It prints:

```
Bill 2011-01-01 3
Bill 2011-01-02 3
Bill 2011-01-03 3
Bill 2011-01-05 1
Bill 2011-01-07 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module is very good for working with dates, which will be much cleaner than doing the string comparisons you are currently using.

Here is an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

def add_month(dt):
    # Normally you would use timedelta, but timedelta doesn't work with months
    return dt.replace(year=dt.year + (dt.month==12), month=(dt.month%12) + 1)

data = ['Bill 01/01/2011', 'Bill 02/01/2011', 'Bill 03/01/2011', 'Bill 05/01/2011', 'Bill 07/01/2011']
dates = [datetime.strptime(line.split(' ')[1], '%m/%d/%Y') for line in data]
buffer = [data[0]]
for i, date in enumerate(dates[1:]):
    if add_month(dates[i]) == date:
        buffer.append(data[i+1])
    else:
        print '\n'.join(line + ' ' + str(len(buffer)) for line in buffer)
        buffer = [data[i+1]]

print '\n'.join(line + ' ' + str(len(buffer)) for line in buffer)
```

I went with the assumption that your dates were in the form `month/day/year`, if they are actually `day/month/year` then you can add `from datetime import timedelta` to the top, change the format in `datetime.strptime()` to `'%d/%m/%y'`, and instead of `add_month(dates[i]) == date`, use `date - dates[i] == timedelta(days=1)`.